# Supporting multiple versions of web-services

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

I have web-services implemented with Dropwizrad. These web-services are being developed for an mobile app. Consider a scenarios where  version 1.0 of the application is out, multiple users are accessing it. Now there major changes to be done to web-services which will be compatible with only new version of the application. To tackle this I will have to host two versions of web-services, one for the legacy users and other for the latest version of the application. Is there any way I can **run different versions of the same web-services in the same container**. 
So that clients could make choice between the the version of web-services to be user more like

http://myHost/web-services-v1

http://myHost/web-services-v2

Comment: You could change the path, `myHost/web-service/{version}/` and people could access it like `myHost/web-service/1/...`, `...vice/2/...` and so on.

Comment: Thanks prompt reply. I can always change the application context and the run the web-services. But my problem is how to run these two different versions in the same container Also I will be hosting this versions on the same instance. So just change in the application context is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the web service is self-contained in its own webapp (war file), with its own dependencies (`WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib`), then you can run 2 separate webapps on 2 different context roots and neither one will be aware of each other.